# Wordpress pagination numbers

Tags: css, wordpress

After doing a lot of trial an error on WP pagination, I've decided to seek help here. The code that I am using to display navigation is :

```
function wp_pagination() {
global $wp_query;
$big = 12345678;
$page_format = paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
'type'  => 'array'
) );
if( is_array($page_format) ) {
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0 ) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
        echo '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
        echo '<li><span>'. $paged . ' of ' . $wp_query->max_num_pages .'</span></li>';
        foreach ( $page_format as $page ) {
                echo "<li>$page</li>";
        }
       echo '</ul></div>';
}
}
```

It works but the problem is the following:
When on page 1, it displays less numbers than lets say we are on page 5. It's a problem for me to center it on page because paginaton content grows and shrinks (depending on a page number)

http://tinypic.com/r/350ngjp/8

How can I make it display same number of fields , no matter the page? Or center it no matter the size. I used

```
margin:auto;
```

and fixed container width but it goes left (page 1) or center(page 5).

Many thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `'mid_size' => 1` parameter to paginate_links array. This will make sure there is single page number visible to the left and right of the current page number, so in total 3. Something like `<<Back 1 ... 4 ... 19 Next>>`
[CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links#Parameters)

And css to center the links

```
.pagination {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I added 'mid_size' => 1 to pagination function , but nothing changed. Weird.... Now I made it show all the numbers, and I center it on  the left. Best sollution.